# VBA save binary

Tags: vba, binary

I have a simple code

```
FileName = "h:\OutStr.txt"
Dim BA(1) As Byte
BA(0) = 99
BA(1) = 100

Open FileName For Binary Access Write As #1
lWritePos = 1
Put #1, lWritePos, BA
Close #1
```

After saving, OutStr.txt contains two bytes as expected: 99 and 100.

But the result is different in case I am using a function:

```
Sub BytesToBinaryFile(out_file_name_, vData_)

    Open out_file_name_ For Binary Access Write As #1
    lWritePos = 1
    Put #1, lWritePos, vData_
    Close #1

End Sub


FileName = "h:\OutStr.txt"
Dim BA(1) As Byte
BA(0) = 99
BA(1) = 100

Call BytesToBinaryFile(FileName, BA)
```

In this case the saved file conatins a sequence of bytes, like:

17 32 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 100

Could anybody explain me the difference in the results?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
Sub BytesToBinaryFile(out_file_name_, vData_)
```

both variables are of type `Variant`.

Declare them properly and it works as expected in the function as well

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub BytesToBinaryFile(ByVal out_file_name_ As String, ByRef vData_() As Byte)
    Open out_file_name_ For Binary Access Write As #1
    
    Const lWritePos As Long = 1
    Put #1, lWritePos, vData_

    Close #1
End Sub
```

I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

And declare all variables as good as possible and avoid `Variant` whenever you can.